# How to store function in tuple that references value same tuple?

Tags: python

If I have a tuple defined like the one below, what is the best way for the argument in the Callable reference the value on the left?

```
Tuple[Any, Callable[[Any], List[Tuple[Any, int]]]]
```

For example:

```
def f(i:int) -> List[Tuple[Any,int]]:
  ...
t = (12345678, f)
print( t[1]() )
# > (12345678, [123,456,789])
```

Comment: I think what I'm trying to do is probably a list comprehension with a list of these tuples and in that context I can pass the argument in.

Comment: Not a direct answer, but perhaps the function in the 2nd part of the tuple can be converted to a function that always takes the first arg and returns another function?

Comment: Is `print( t[1]() )` correct?  Doesn't the call to the callable require an integer argument, like `print( t[1](<some int arg>) )` ? - also, maybe I'm being dense, but I don't see what `Callable[]` represents in the first sample.  Is that valid Python syntax or is that some kind of metasyntax?

Comment: I'm wondering if what you might want is a bound method reference instead of a function reference.  If you did that, you could tie data to the callable by having it exist in the instance that the method is bound to.  This may do you no good at all given what you want to do.  I just thought it made sense to mention the idea. - I honestly have no idea what you're trying to accomplish here.  Maybe you describing a use case would help.

Comment: @Adgezaza Your question looks like an [XY Problem](https://xyproblem.info/). Please try to explain what you're actually trying to achieve by doing this.

Comment: This is for a library that takes takes an set of values and apply a parsing function to the value. Because this is a library, the appropriate parsing and hashing function is attributed by the library user and applied downstream by the library for specific steps.

Working forward I realize I can run a list comprehension and apply the functions then?

Comment: @Steve I'm trying not to use any Classes and write as many pure functions as possible.

Comment: BTW, f might have c and c++ bindings for performance and would be selected by either an alias type/library and/or the user.

Comment: If `f` is stored in two tuples `(12345678, f)` and `(87654321 ,f)`, how do you want `f` to behave when invoked?

Comment: `f` in this case splits the digts up in groups of 3 so it would output `[123,456,789]` and `[988,654,321]` (note: added the ninth digit) but if you have `f` and `g` g can do something be paired for a `g` specific result.

Comment: @Adgezaza Why isn't `[f(v) for v, f in items]` an acceptable solution? Or if the same parsing function is being used for the entire set of values, why not simply `map(f, values)`? It's hard to see what the actual problem is here.

Comment: @ekhumoro it is. I didn't think of it before I wrote the question. I'm moving forward that way for now if you want to answer.